# Firebase Performance issue with large data set

Tags: performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

We have built the app based on Firebase, and we have more than 7M users authenticated with Firebase Auth and every user has its data stored on /users/UID path indexed by a score property to allow leadboard limited to top 10.

We had issues with performance and introduced many optimization to the clients writes request and is running smooth (with more than 10K simultaneous connections).

But once number of users get higher and higher now we are encountering performance issues for lower simultaneous real time connection (around 5K).
is this an inner limitation to how many users firebase auth could handle?